# Clojure : Read an edn file line by line

Tags: clojure, readfile

I have written data like that in a file (kind of)

```
{:a 25 :b 28}
{:a 2 :b 50}
...
```

I want to have a lazy sequence of these maps.

There are around 40 millions of lines. I can also write chunks of 10000 but I do not thnik it will change the way the functions are written (`mapcat` instead of `map`)

To read it, I wrote

```
(with-open [affectations (io/reader "dev-resources/affectations.edn")]
  (map read-string affectations))
```

The problem is that Clojure tells

```
Don't know how to create ISeq from : java.io.BufferedReader
```

To be honest I understand nothing on the java.io namespace.
I would like to have a lazy sequence of the data in the file but I do not know how to turn the stream into strings and then collections.

Any idea ?

Is this `read-line` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `java.io.BufferedReader` to `map` whereas `map` expects a seq.

You need to use `line-seq` to produce a (lazy) seq of lines from your file:

```
(with-open [affectations (io/reader "dev-resources/affectations.edn")]
  (map read-string (lazy-seq affectations)))
```

Remember, that you need to force all your side effects on the data read from a resource opened in `with-open` within its scope, otherwise you will get errors.

One option is to just force the whole seq of text lines from your files and return it using `doall`. However, this solution could read all your data into memory which doesn't seem practical.

I guess you need to execute some logic for each of the line from the file and you don't need to keep all those parsed collections in memory. In such case you could pass a function representing that logic into your function handling reading your file:

```
(defn process-file [filename process-fn]
  (with-open [reader (io/reader filename)]
    (doseq [line (line-seq reader)]
      (-> line
        (read-string)
        (process-fn)))))
```

This function will read your file line by line converting each of it individually using `read-string` and calling your `process-fn` function. `process-file` will return `nil`.

Comment: Thanks , I removed the "with-open" to keep the file open, otherwise I took your code. I also wrote the first operation (writing file) by chunks of 100000 to speed up the code. Unfortunately I do not apply any logic and I don't understand why Clojure uses so much memory while pandas (Python) is completely ok with this data. I have a XmX parameter as 13 Gb my ram is almost all used so that the code is slow. I avoid using def but still memory usage is versy high. I must compute data at some point because I use some group-by and left joins.

Comment: Not wrapping with `with-open` your logic handling resources like files or streams might result in leaks in file descriptors and other system resources so you should be careful.
It's hard to say why your Clojure version is slower than the Python one without more detailed information how you do it in both cases.

Comment: Thanks, I think I know why pandas has a better memory management in my case. In the past I observed that when you define two tables based on the same data modulo some operations (like groupby maybe) they rely on the same data on memory. In my case, I have "many" tables derived from a base table so in Clojure, I have to duplicate memory in a way... For the with-open, when I close it I read no data in memory strangely... I had a "read timed out" in my code, maybe it's because of it, I will investigate but I think it is Google Big Query